# Flag conda packages unsafe/experimental, disallow package install

Tags: conda

I am looking for a way to mark a particular conda package hosted on, say, an HTTP server to be marked "experimental" such that a client's `conda install` command will install the next most recent package instead.

The use case is: I am building release candidate packages that I want to install on our QA machines, but I do not want other developers to accidentally update their environment with the new package. Since the release candidate package has a higher build string than the stable package (e.g. `2.0.0rc1` vs. `1.9.7`), conda will install the release candidate instead. On the other hand, I would like to distribute the release candidate packages using the mechanism I've already set up (the HTTP server) so that I can install them on the QA machines, perhaps with a `--force` flag. I would like to mark the packages "disallow install" on the server as opposed to asking all of the developers edit their `~/.condarc`.

If the configuration I just described is not possible, are there any alternatives? The only thing I can think is to host another package repo that contains only the release candidate/experimental packages. Is this approach typical of what other package managers do?

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the "alpha" packages a label when you upload them. This effectively puts them on a different channel that must be specified when installing, either in the configuration or for a specific install command. The option is detailed here: https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda-cloud/commandreference under the "upload" section (sorry I can't direct link). The command is essentially

```
anaconda upload -l dev /path/to/mypackage-1.0.0a1-py36_0.tar.gz
                ^^^^^^
          This is the label assigned
```

To install from a label, just specify it as a channel

```
conda install -c mychannel/label/dev mypackage
                          ^^^^^^^^^^
                  Include this on your channel
```

If that label isn't specified in the install command (or in the user configuration) then the install won't find the alpha package!

See also [here](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda-repository/user/using) under the heading "Label" for more information.